# Add style to pseudo-class keywords in CSS with listings

Tags: color, listings, css, coding

**Problem:**

Adding specific color to pseudo-class keywords in CSS using listings. For example, the pseudo-classes `:link`, `:visited`, etc should be colored differently.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Colors
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.75, 1, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlack}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 1}
\definecolor{editorOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.5, 1, 0}
\definecolor{editorDarkOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.8, 0.9, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.35, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  CSS
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Targets the colon in inline CSS code
\makeatletter
\def\colorcolonother#1#2{%
  \expandafter\ifx\the\lst@token:%
    \color{#1}%
  \else
    \color{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  CSS
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstdefinelanguage{CSS3}{
  stringstyle=\colorcolonother{editorBlue}{editorPurple},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{editorBlue},
  identifierstyle=\color{editorPink},
  %
  sensitive=true,
  % Line numbers
  xleftmargin={14pt},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  firstnumber=1,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numberstyle=\color{editorBlack},
  frame=l,
  % Keywords
  keywords=[2]{%
  % CSS properties
    color
  },%
  otherkeywords={!important},
  morecomment=[l][\color{darkgray}]{//},
  morecomment=[s][\color{darkgray}]{/*}{*/},
  alsoletter={!.,\#\*},
  morestring=[s]{:}{;},
  alsodigit={!-:},
  escapeinside={`}{'}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  HTML
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,
  tagstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  markfirstintag=true,
  morecomment=[s][\color{darkgray}]{<!-}{-->},
  alsoletter={!-'},
  keywords={}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Code style
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstset{%
  % General design
  inputencoding=utf8,
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\upshape\lst@ifdisplaystyle\tiny\fi,
  frame=single,
  float,
  belowskip=0pt,
  escapeinside=`',
  % line-numbers
  xleftmargin={14pt},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  firstnumber=1,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numberstyle=\color{black},
  % Code design
  identifierstyle=\color{editorOrange},
  keywordstyle=\color{editorPink},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  stringstyle=\color{editorPurple},
  % Code
  language=HTML5,
  alsolanguage=CSS3,
  alsodigit={.:},
  tabsize=2,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keepspaces=true,
  extendedchars=true,
  breaklines=false
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=CSS3,numbers=left,firstnumber=1]
/* Correct */
a {
  color: #555555 !important;
}
/* Incorrect
   color: should be blue
   :link should be purple
*/
a:link {
  color: #555555;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Desired output:**

- Identifiers (`a`) should be in pink
- Pseudo-classes (`:link`) should be in purple
- Properties (`color:`) should be in blue
- Values (`#555555`) should be in purple
- Brackets (`{` and `}`) should be in black